# How to remove special symbols from a string using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have

```
String str1="** Rs. 55.20 **";
String str2="";
```

now i want regex that gives me a result  as:

```
  str2="Rs. 55.20";
```

in short I want to remove **   from beggining and end of the string.

Thank u in advance ..

Comment: Let us know what code you tried out

Comment: show them to me, show them to me, unclasp your code and set those puppies free

Comment: see..i have "** Rs. 55.20 **" and i want "Rs. 55.20" whatever the way is  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work for you:

```
String str1="** Rs. 55.20 **";
String str2 = str1.replaceAll("(^\\*\\*\\s)|(\\s\\*\\*$)","");
```

Check it here http://ideone.com/pqXXYd

Comment: you have to add `^` and `$` to make it replace from begin and end. Currently your code replaces `**` from this input too: `My ** Done`

Comment: @SabujHassan yep, probably (it depends if author wants to replace not only at the beginning and at the end), edited the answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("\\*\\* (.*) \\*\\*");
Matcher m= p.matcher(str1);
str2 = m.group(1);
```